# how to store lengthy json string in application insight log , in the array format?

Tags: azure-application-insights

let I have JSON data like below

> {     "name" : "Admin",   "age" : 36,     "rights" : [ "admin", "editor",
>   "contributor" ] }, {  "name" : "Admin",   "age" : 36,     "rights" : [
>   "admin", "editor", "contributor" ] }

if I have above JSON string like 1000 times, how I need to store in the application insight log

I just gave sample JSON formate, in my project I will use 1000 JSON tags need to store in the application insight but which is not supporting to store, even after splitting the string and store in the custom dimensions

if I have

Comment: Short answer: you don't. App Insights is for operational logging. You could create an event or trace per json object and store it in the telemetry item properties but you might be better of using blob or table storage for this.

Comment: @PeterBons thank you, is it possible to store large amount json string by splitting into chunks and add to the telemetry item properties?

Comment: @tejaraju, yes it's possible. but you should take care of the size limit. And also, as per PeterBons mentioned, for storing, you'd better use blob storage. Not sure why you use application insights for storing such data.